# How to format tables in SQL to store data for weekly stock updates?

Tags: sql, database, format

I am beginning a project where I am tracking weekly stock updates for a bar's drink's stock, however I am unsure how to format this data in SQL tables.

The data I am collecting for each specific drink includes:

1. the week-start date
2. stock at the start of this week
3. stock at the end of this week
4. total stock sold

How would I format this so I could retrieve the stock data for a specific drink from a specific week?

My original idea was to have a `drinks` table that includes:

```
id,
name,
category,
price
```

...and a `stock` table that includes:

```
drink_id,
week_start,
start_stock,
end_stock,
total_sold
```

...however I am unsure that this would function how I intend.

Comment: U want the total stock sold for the week? if so U can calculate it.
if U want the total stock sold for this specific drink U can move the total sold to the drinks table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea of having a '**drinks**' table and a '**stock**' table is a good start. To ensure that you can retrieve the stock data for a specific drink from a specific week, you could add a unique constraint to the '**stock**' table that ensures that there can only be one entry for a specific drink and week.

Here's an example of how you could set up the tables:

**Drinks table:**

| Column Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | INTEGER |
| name | TEXT |
| category | TEXT |
| price | DECIMAL |

**Stock table:**

| Column Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | INTEGER |
| drink_id | INTEGER |
| week_start | DATE |
| start_stock | INTEGER |
| end_stock | INTEGER |
| total_sold | INTEGER |

The 'drinks' table has an ID column that is used as a foreign key in the '**stock**' table to associate each entry with a specific drink. The 'week_start' column in the 'stock' table is a DATE data type, which allows you to filter by a specific week.

You could then add a unique constraint to the '**stock**' table to ensure that there can only be one entry for a specific drink and week. Here's an example of how you could do that:

```sql
ALTER TABLE stock ADD CONSTRAINT unique_drink_week UNIQUE (drink_id, week_start);
```

This unique constraint will prevent you from inserting duplicate entries for a specific drink and week, ensuring that you can retrieve the stock data for a specific drink from a specific week. Please note that script is for **Microsoft SQL Server**. It can vary according to the database engine you are using.